# Device Manager fails to start on a macOS Server 5.2

Tags: macos, server.app, open-directory, profile-manager

I have setup a working Open Directory Master on on `Mac-Server-1` running macOS Sierra and macOS Server 5.2 (latest as of today).  I have also successfully started the Device Manager and enrolled a client computer with no problem.

I have now also setup a working Open Directory Replica on `Mac-Server-2` running MacOS Sierra and macOS Server 5.2.  However, when I try to activate the Device Manager on the Replica, it stays Disabled.

Is this by design that Device Manager can only be active on the Master?  Or is this a bug?

Steps:

1. In macOS Server -> Profile Manger -> Device Manager, status is `Disabled`
2. In macOS Server -> Profile Manger -> Device Manager, I click `Setup...` button
3. New window appears telling me I can manage devices.  I click `Next`
4. The window now changes and asks me for a Name, E-mail, Telephone, and Address (presumably to generate a certificate?)
5. I enter the info, and click `Next`
6. The next window appears, telling me to click `Finish`.  I do.
7. The window disappears, returning me to the macOS Server -> Profile Manger window, where the status of Device Manager still shows as `Disabled`

Ideas?

**Edit1**: I tried uninstalling Server.app and deleting /Library/Server/* and reinstalling the Replica from scratch.  Same behavior.

**Edit2**: I tried reinstalling the entire server from scratch.  Same behavior.

Comment: no one has any experience with a multi-site macOS (or OS X) Server setup?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Profile/Device manager needs the full Certificate authority (to sign profiles) that is only available on the OD master, so it is probably by design.